# Use jQuery to select nav item where href = location.hash

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select a nav item that has an href equal to the current location hash and then apply a class. For some reason this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $('#nav .btn[href="'+ window.location.hash +'"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: what do `$('#nav .btn[href="'+ window.location.hash +'"]').length` returns?

Comment: It returns "1" via the console.

Comment: Ahhh... I figured it out. Thanks, Milind for the suggestion to look in the console... I never use it that often and it helped me see the problem... I needed to do a `.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

Derp, it was actually working, it's just that I had some css in there to make it look disabled. The solution for me was to use the exact code I originally posted but stack an extra step:

```
$('#nav .btn[href="'+ window.location.hash +'"]').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
```